# Upstart causing 502

Tags: 14.04

I am trying to re-deploy to my ubuntu instance, and I am getting 502.  My nginx and application logs are empty, but upstart logs keep saying:

`Meteor requires Node v0.10.36 or later.`

Ive done an `npm install` in my server directory, so Im not sure why that's happening (never happened before).  What I can't figure out is why `status application` yields:

`application stop/waiting`

but when I do `start application`, I get:

`application start/running, process 29016`

Are these issues related?